# get enum raw values from [Any] without downcasting

Tags: swift, enums, downcast

Say I have 5 different enums of String type, enum1:String, enum2:String ...

I have an array [Any] whose type is one of the 5 enums, is there a way to get the raw values of the array of enums without downcasting it to the specific enum type?

Comment: no, It cannot be done unless the enum type is know to compiler. So downcast is must

Comment: I agree with @kathayatnk, because according to [Apple’s Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html): `Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types`. So, if you don't let the compiler know that you're working with an enumeration, you will not be able to get the raw values of the enumeration cases.

Comment: If you don't want to downcasting, why do you use Any?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of wrapping the different enums in an array of Any, you can create an new enum type which holds the other enum values. So you are always type safe and have access to raw value.

```
enum Enum1: String {
    case foo1 = "foo"
    case foo2 = "foo2"
}

enum Enum2: String {
    case bla1 = "bla"
    case bla2 = "bla2"
}


enum EnumType {
    case enum1(Enum1)
    case enum2(Enum2)
    case enum3(Enum2)
}

let array: [EnumType] = [
    EnumType.enum1(.foo1),
    EnumType.enum1(.foo2),
    EnumType.enum2(.bla1)]

for item in array {
    switch item {
    case .enum1(let value):
        print(value)
    case .enum2(let value):
        print(value)
    case .enum3(let value):
        print(value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this:

```
Enum(rawValue:INDEX)
```

So for instance, if you have a Currency Enum:

```
public enum Currency : Int {

case EUR
case GBP
case SK
case NOK
case USD

public static let values : [Currency] = [EUR, GBP, SK, NOK, USD]
```

}

You can get the value like this:

```
Currency(rawValue: 0)
```

It will return EUR.

Comment: Seems your answer is not related to the question.